# Handling click events in android kotlin: setOnClickListener only works when double-clicked

Tags: android, kotlin, onclicklistener

I have a button in a DialogFragment to go back to another activity. But it only works when double-clicked. I'm running out of ideas. In my XML file, I've already tried the following (combined in different ways, but none of them worked)

My whole fragment XML file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="600dp"
    android:layout_height="500dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:background="@drawable/bg_rounded_white"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="@dimen/vertical_margin">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_payment_done_title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/vertical_margin"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text="@string/payment_approved_title"
        android:textColor="@color/bg_color"
        android:textSize="@dimen/text_large"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_payment_message"
        android:layout_width="550dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/vertical_margin"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:minHeight="100dp"
        android:text="Payment done!"
        android:textColor="@color/black_overlay"
        android:textSize="@dimen/text_medium"
        android:textStyle="normal" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="600dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="46dp"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/rpv_btn_no_payment_done"
            android:layout_width="250dp"
            android:layout_height="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="@drawable/bg_rounded_light_blue"
            android:duplicateParentState="true"
            android:text="@string/txt_btn_no"
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            android:textColor="@color/white_text_color"
            android:textSize="@dimen/text_medium"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:visibility="gone" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/rpv_btn_yes_payment_done"
            android:layout_width="250dp"
            android:layout_height="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/vertical_margin"
            android:background="@drawable/bg_rounded_light_blue"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
            android:focusedByDefault="true"
            android:text="@string/txt_btn_exit"
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            android:textColor="@color/white_text_color"
            android:textSize="@dimen/text_medium"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

As for my DialogFragment, I've tried to put my setOnClickListener inside the onViewCreated() method, and then inside the onStart() and after inside the onResume() methods. It keeps working only when double-clicked. I also have a timer that makes the dialog disappear after 10 secs and then it leads me to the activity I want anyway, so it isn't so much of a problem, but I really need and want to fix it. If I set the timer to 5 secs or lower, of course, it gives the impression that the button works when clicked once, but it actually doesn't.

```
class PaymentDoneDialogFragment : DialogFragment() {

    private lateinit var mYesBtn: Button
    private lateinit var mActionYes: () -> Unit

override fun onViewCreated(view: View, @Nullable savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
    dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false)
    dialog.window.requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE)
    dialog.window.setDimAmount(.85f)
    dialog.window.setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE)
    dialog.setCancelable(false)
    dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false)
    dialog.window.decorView.systemUiVisibility = activity?.window!!.decorView.systemUiVisibility
    dialog.window.clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE)
    mDialogTitle = view.find(R.id.tv_payment_done_title)
    if (mTitle != null) {
        mDialogTitle.text = mTitle
    }
    mYesBtn = view.find(R.id.rpv_btn_yes_payment_done)
    if (mYesTitle != null) {
        mYesBtn.text = mYesTitle
    }
    mYesBtn.setOnClickListener {
        if (mMessage == null) {
            (activity as PaymentActivity).nextScreensaverActivity()
        } else {
            mActionYes()
        } 
        activity?.supportFragmentManager?.beginTransaction()?.remove(this)?.commit()
    }

    if (mMessage != null) {
        mMessageTextView = view.find(R.id.tv_payment_message)
        mMessageTextView?.text = mMessage
        mNoBtn = view.find(R.id.rpv_btn_no_payment_done)
        if (mNoTitle != null)
            mNoBtn.text = mNoTitle
        mNoBtn.visibility = View.VISIBLE
        mNoBtn.setOnClickListener {
            mActionNo()
            activity?.supportFragmentManager?.beginTransaction()?.remove(this)?.commit()
        }
    }
}
```

Does anyone have some clue?

Comment: I added a breakpoint at `if(mMessage == null)` in my listener, and it only stops for debugging after double-clicked

Comment: just to be sure, mYesBtn is not working?

Comment: It is working, yes, but just after I double-click it. I want it to work at first (and only one) click.

Comment: @Onik sure, I've edited my XML file with both mYesBTn and mNoBtn

Comment: Should I use setOnTouchListener instead of setOnClickListener? Would it make any difference?

Comment: @Onik when I first started, there was no "focusable-clickable" stuff at all... I added them when I began to search the solution for this problem

Comment: @Onik you mean the comments in my DialogFragment code? Anyway, I've already removed the "focusable..." stuff, and am still getting the same problem. Getting rid of the timer also didn't make any difference at all.

Comment: No, I literally meant comments, like this one :)... Well, bad news are also news, right?) Now, what if you create an Activity with only the DialogFragment?

Answer (score 0):

You should remove `android:clickable="false"` and `android:focusable="false"` from `LinearLayout` child

Comment: Also i see that you have some properties on second button. Did you remove them? `android:clickable="true"  android:focusable="true" android:focusableInTouchMode="true" android:focusedByDefault="true"`